# Error on Paysafe Card Payment API?

Tags: api-key, netbanx-api, paysafe

This may sound stupid but I keep getting this error for every request that I make for the Card Payments API.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "5270",
    "message": "The credentials provided with the request do not have permission to access the data requested.",
    "links": [
      {
        "rel": "errorinfo",
        "href": "https://developer.optimalpayments.com/en/documentation/cardpayments/error-5270"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The error seems to indicate that I do not have permission to do something. Is this an access issue as I think I am using the proper key? Has anyone ever seen this error with Paysafe?

Comment: yes this is an access issue with the credentials shared with you.. and this question asked directly to the support team @ Card Payment Api provider  will result it better answers to you then over here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Crazyshezy is correct. Write to Paysafe with the key that you are using and they will be able to isolate what permissions that you have or may not have with your API key.

Answer (score 1):

i was getting same error. It was due to card expiry year. It should be 4 digit year(e.g 2017) but i was sending 2 digit year(17).